# Is it possible to use System.Diagnostics.Trace as a form of commons logging for .net?

Tags: .net, logging

I was wondering if there is any way that I could leverage the methods on System.Diagnostics.Trace, as a form of commons logging for my .Net libraries. Rather than include dependencies in those libraries for log4net or CommonsNet (which appears to be a similar project to commons logging for java in .Net), can I use the built in methods?

I see that it is possible to add listeners to this trace output, however are there going to be performance penalties for calling `Trace.TraceError`, `Trace.TraceWarning` or `Trace.TraceInformation` from performance critical code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already designed for this purpose so using them for what they were meant to be is perfectly valid. Just add this to your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

On the other hand, yes they will affect the performance of your application in performance sensitive area. If you're so concerned about that, rather use [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) like below:

```
log.Trace(m=>m("value= {0}", obj.Value));
```

This way, only if the LogLevel.Trace is enabled this function will be evaluated. When disabled, there will be minimal performance penalty.

Comment: I'd probably not want to disable logging in a high performance scenario, just deal with it in a different, and lower priority thread. ie, append all logging onto a queue and process it later, as CPU headroom allowed. Hmm, some quick tests indicate that appending to a queue would be several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I guess <trace autoflush="false"> part already does that for you via caching all trace requests in memory and writing them all at once when app exits.

Comment: I did a little test with all three modes (trace, trace without autoflush, and appending to a queue). https://gist.github.com/986378. Appending to a queue came out a clear winner.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your questions is 'Yes'. For the first, you would need to implement (or use  existing) [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx).

For the second, there will be performance penalties, as to whether or not the penalty is meaningful really depends on the perf reqs and the performance of your logger.